# c++: шаблон из объекта

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++

Здравствуйте!

Есть несколько классов:

```
class Base {
    Base *createObject() {
        return new Base();
    }
    ...
}

class A : public Base {
    ... 
}

class B : public Base {
    ... 
}

template <class T> class BaseHolder {
     BaseHolder();
}
```

Так вот, в классе `Base` мне нужно создать объект типа `BaseHolder` с `template` равному типу класса, в котором это происходит. То-есть, если я создаю объект типа `BaseHolder` в классе `A`, я получу:

```
 BaseHoler holder = BaseHolder <A> ();
```

A в классе `B` соответсвенно:

```
 BaseHoler holder = BaseHolder <B> ();
```

Как реализовать?

**Update**

Вместо строчки `return new Base();` нужно вернуть объект типа, в котором вызывается метод. То-есть, при вызове метода `createObject()` у объекта типа `А`, будет возвращен новый объект типа `A`;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы хотите что-то такое?

```
template <class T>
class BaseHolder {
public:
    BaseHolder(){}
};


class Base {
};

class A : public Base {

public:
    A() = default;
    BaseHolder<A> holder;

};

class B : public Base {

public:
    B() = default;
    BaseHolder<B> holder;

};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    A a;
    B b;
}
```

Если нет - поясните подробнее и понятнее, что вам нужно...

**Update** После уточнения в комментарии - посмотрите вот это:

```
template <class T>
class BaseHolder {
public:
    BaseHolder(){}
};


template <class T>
class Base {
    BaseHolder<T> holder;
};

class A : public Base<A> {

public:
    A() = default;

};

class B : public Base<B> {

public:
    B() = default;

};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    A a;
    B b;
}
```

**Update2** Если и это не то, что надо - удаляю ответ. Когда нет нормального ТЗ, получается ХЗ...

```
class Base {
public:
    Base *createObject() {
        return new Base();
    }

};

class A : public Base {

public:
    A() = default;
    Base *createObject() {
        return new A();
    }

};

class B : public Base {

public:
    B() = default;
    Base *createObject() {
        return new B();
    }

};
```

Comment: только нужно в методе класса `Base`  создать объект `BaseHolder`.

Comment: Объект *какого* класса? Вы же не знаете, что там будет. Но! Вы можете сделать Base шаблонным.

Comment: объект BaseHolder. В этом то и загвостка. Можно ли узнать тип класса из его же метода?

Comment: Посмотрите дополненный ответ - это устроит?

Comment: Поправил вопрос.

Comment: Опять не легче... Ну просто напишите в каждом классе свою функцию, например.

Comment: Тоже вариант, но суб-классов очень много, возможно, это не лучший вариант.

Comment: Вобщем, определитесь для начала сами, чего вы хотите...

Comment: Просто нужно определить тип класса-исполнителя метожжа в методе родителя.

Comment: Родитель **ничего не знает о потомках**. Максимум, что вы можете сделать - это сделать метод виртуальным, и перекрывать его в потомке.

Comment: @reload, а чем вас crtp не устроил из первого **Update** в этом ответе?

Comment: @Harry Человек, видимо, хочет того, чего можно добиться в Java при помощи рефлексии. Но проблема в том, что в C++ нет рефлексии.